# Convert product item options in an order to readable array

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, items

When i print the order item there's an index product_options, i want to make the value is readable, because the current value seems like encoded or something

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
 $data = $item->getData();
 print_r($data['product_options']);
 break;
}
```

here's the result:

```
"product_options": "a:1:{s:15:\"info_buyRequest\";a:5:{s:4:\"uenc\";s:112:\"aHR0cDovL3ZpdGFtaW5kaXNrb24uY29tL2luZGV4LnBocC9maWx0ZXJwcm9kdWN0cy9maWx0ZXJwcm9kdWN0cy9sb2FkUHJvZHVjdHNCbG9jay8,\";s:7:\"product\";s:1:\"2\";s:8:\"form_key\";s:16:\"z0Ntafc7OHiqMgIx\";s:7:\"options\";s:4:\"cart\";s:3:\"qty\";i:1;}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

use [php function unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.unserialize.php) or just call `getProductOptions()` on your order item ($item)